# Use of pattern matching generate JavaScript languagae Service has been disabled

Tags: javascript, c#, pattern-matching

If use pattern matching for checking type of variable then it raise **The JavaScript language service has been disabled**

```
var exception = ex as XYZException; //it has no issue
```

but if :

```
 if (ex is XYZException exception) // it generate error of JaVascript Service Disabled
```

Please see screenshot :

[image: Screenshot of Buid Outpu]

*UPDATE* : Fixed by updating Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need to update the visual studio.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#knownissues